# How to GET volley JSONArray in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-volley

I'm new in **Volley JSONArray**. I unable to **setText** in **txtResponse** because I always getting this error at **onErrorResponse**.

This is my **Logcat**

> ......com.example.simplevolley.simplevolley W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"com_branch_id":7,"com_branch_comId":1,"com_branch_name":"JT Temerloh","com_branch_manager":"Tn Hj Ahmad Bin Hj Mohd Sidin","com_branch_addr":"No.58, Jalan Ibrahim (Jln Masjid Abu Bakar)","com_branch_region":"Temerloh","com_branch_state":"PAHANG","com_branch_country":"MALAYSIA","com_branch_poscode":"28000","com_branch_email":"tmlh@juaratravel.com.my","com_branch_licence":null,"com_branch_phoneNum":"09-2965625","com_branch_fax":null,"com_branch_fb":null,"com_branch_ig":null},{"com_branch_id":9,"com_branch_comId":1,"com_branch_name":"JT Nibong Tebal","com_branch_manager":"Pejabat Penang","com_branch_addr":"No. 10, Tingkat Atas, Jln Pekaka 1, Tmn Pekaka,","com_branch_region":"Nibong Tebal","com_branch_state":"PULAU PINANG","com_branch_country":"MALAYSIA","com_branch_poscode":"14300","com_branch_email":"pen@juaratravel.com.my","com_branch_licence":null,"com_branch_phoneNum":"05-7171877","com_branch_fax":"057161877","com_branch_fb":null,"com_branch_ig":null}......

I want to read this **JSON** lines but because it start with **JSONArray** I'm so confused.

```
{
"res": true,
"datas": [
    {
        "com_branch_id": 7,
        "com_branch_comId": 1,
        "com_branch_name": "JT Temerloh",
        "com_branch_manager": "Tn Hj Ahmad Bin Hj Mohd Sidin",
        "com_branch_addr": "No.58, Jalan Ibrahim (Jln Masjid Abu Bakar)",
        "com_branch_region": "Temerloh",
        "com_branch_state": "PAHANG",
        "com_branch_country": "MALAYSIA",
        "com_branch_poscode": "28000",
        "com_branch_email": "tmlh@juaratravel.com.my",
        "com_branch_licence": null,
        "com_branch_phoneNum": "09-2965625",
        "com_branch_fax": null,
        "com_branch_fb": null,
        "com_branch_ig": null
    },
    {
        "com_branch_id": 9,
        "com_branch_comId": 1,
        "com_branch_name": "JT Nibong Tebal",
        "com_branch_manager": "Pejabat Penang",
        "com_branch_addr": "No. 10, Tingkat Atas, Jln Pekaka 1, Tmn Pekaka,",
        "com_branch_region": "Nibong Tebal",
        "com_branch_state": "PULAU PINANG",
        "com_branch_country": "MALAYSIA",
        "com_branch_poscode": "14300",
        "com_branch_email": "pen@juaratravel.com.my",
        "com_branch_licence": null,
        "com_branch_phoneNum": "05-7171877",
        "com_branch_fax": "057161877",
        "com_branch_fb": null,
        "com_branch_ig": null
    },]}
```

I need to get all **datas** value. This is my code

```
 private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {
    showpDialog();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("res", response.toString());

                    try {


                        jsonResponse = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {


                            JSONObject branchi = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            JSONObject branch = branchi.getJSONObject("datas");


                            Integer com_branch_id = Integer.valueOf(branch.getString("com_branch_id"));
                            Integer com_branch_comId = Integer.valueOf(branch.getString("com_branch_comId"));
                            String com_branch_name = branch.getString("com_branch_name");
                            String com_branch_manager = branch.getString("com_branch_manager");
                            String com_branch_addr = branch.getString("com_branch_addr");
                            String com_branch_region = branch.getString("com_branch_region");
                            String com_branch_state = branch.getString("com_branch_state");
                            String com_branch_country = branch.getString("com_branch_country");
                            String com_branch_poscode = branch.getString("com_branch_poscode");
                            String com_branch_email = branch.getString("com_branch_email");
                            String com_branch_licence = branch.getString("com_branch_licence");
                            String com_branch_phoneNum = branch.getString("com_branch_phoneNum");
                            String com_branch_fax = branch.getString("datas.com_branch_fax");
                            String com_branch_fb = branch.getString("datas.com_branch_fb");
                            String com_branch_ig = branch.getString("datas.com_branch_ig");


                            jsonResponse = "";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch name: " + com_branch_id + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch manager: " + com_branch_comId + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_name + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_manager + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_addr + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_region + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_state + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_country + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_poscode + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_email + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_licence + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_phoneNum + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_fax + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_fb + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Branch state: " + com_branch_ig + "\n\n";

                        }

                        txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "res" + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        txtResponse.setText(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "res" + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("onErrorResponse", error.getMessage());
            hidepDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

I try to follow other solution but unfortunately I fail and stuck.

Comment: If the json example you posted is the response to your request it is not a JSONArray!

Comment: What I understand is JSON Object --> { ""...""}  and JSON Array --> [ , , , ]

Comment: Use [Gson](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_first_application.htm) and           [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) my friend

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

    JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("datas");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject c = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

         //here you get by json key
         String id = c.getString("com_branch_id");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your Json is not an array(it starts with { implying an object
 json).  Use JsonObjectRequest.
 2) Rather than grabbing the elements,
 in your response, by iterating you can use a jackson2 to map the
 response to your POJO.
 3) You can use jsonschema2pojo to create a
 POJO class

Answer (score 0):

`JsonArrayRequest` will give you response as `JSONArray`. But your response is not `JSONArray`. Its `JSONObject` and that `JSONObject` contains `JSONArray`.

Use `JsonObjectRequest` for your case.

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert you response to Java object.

Make a Java Pojo class that match with your response format. Than convert your response into java object.

```
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            String message = "";
            if (response != null) {
                message = response.toString();
                Post post = null;
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                post = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Post.class);

            } else {
                message = "Response is null";

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give me example code or link to solve my problem.